# Android Mediaplayer not able to play some wowza m4a url on Android devices whose version is 4.3 or higher

Tags: android-mediaplayer, wowza, android-version

Android Mediaplayer not able to play some wowza m4a urls on Android devices whose version is 4.3 or higher. While some are getting played without any efforts on same device.

The same urls are working fine on Android 4.2.2/ 4.1/ & lower version devices.

The logs on wowza are showing play state, but in my app its not getting played. When seeked to some position, it also get tracked on wowza but no sound comes out.....

Can any one suggest me any solution?